# Question regarding how to derive univariate Lasso closed form

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

In the picture we are given a lasso problem. The task is to derive equation (3) from equation (2). We do not need to show that the constraints hold for $\mathbf{w} $.I looked at the solution made by cardinal21 in one other question here regarding this but i could not connect the dots.I know this question is similar but if someone could help me connect the dots it would be great. Also note here x is a vector that is not normalized.
[image: Background]

Comment: Welcome to the community. Could you please include a link in your question to the other question that you mentioned, and can you explain a bit more about where you're getting stuck or what exactly you're confused about?